# Вопрос по расположению второго окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

В общем, есть окно в котором при нажатии кнопки открывается второе окно. И вот вопрос, как сделать чтобы он отображался в центре предыдущего окна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте методы [geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) и [rect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop), чтобы найти разницу точек по центру. Метод [geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) он хранит информацию не только о размере, но и о позиции виджета.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.widget.resize(100, 100)

        button = Qt.QPushButton('Click!', clicked=self.show_and_move)

        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def show_and_move(self):
        self.widget.hide()

        pos = self.geometry().center() - self.widget.rect().center()
        self.widget.move(pos)

        self.widget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(500, 500)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```